# Line numbering of listings

Tags: listings

In the `listings` package, the `stepnumber` option controls the interval of line numbering, but I found there's no such option which controls the starting number. Is there a way that I could show numbers 1,11,21,... rather than 10,20,30,... ?

---

**Update**

I have tried `firstnumber`, and this is not what I want.

I want things like this:

```
   A
 2 B
   C
   D
   E
   F
 7 G
   H
   I
   J
   K
12 L
   M
   N
```

But with `firstnumber=2,stepnumber=5` I get this:

```
   A
   B
   C
 5 D
   E
   F
   G
   H
10 I
   J
   K
   L
   M
15 N
```

Comment: You can use `firstnumber=1, stepnumber=10`. (Section 2.6 of the documentation.)

Comment: @AlanMunn sounds like an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a workaround

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left,firstnumber=4,stepnumber=5,escapeinside={\%}{\%}]
A%\addtocounter{lstnumber}{-3}%
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Use

1. `firstnumber=3` and `\addtocounter{lstnumber}{-2}` if you want the numbering to start at 3;
2. `firstnumber=2` and `\addtocounter{lstnumber}{-1}` if you want the numbering to start at 4;
3. `firstnumber=1` and `\addtocounter{lstnumber}{0}` if you want the numbering to start at 5.

Comment: Nice hacking～～～

Answer (score 3):

The `listings` package allows you to set both the starting number and the interval.  In your specific example:

```
\lstset{numbers=left,firstnumber=1,stepnumber=10}
```

See §2.6 of the documentation for details.

Comment: No, this not works. I have updated my question for explanation.